Why did ZFS import drives that were already labeled as FAULTED?
I am in the process of recovering a degraded array. I just finished backing up the array to a RAID1 mirror, powered down the system, and swapped in my spare for one of the FAULTED disks. To my surprise when I booted up the machine, the other two drives that were previously FAULTED showed as ONLINE.
Why did ZFS import these drives automatically? Is it unaware of drives that had faulted previously between imports? Although this would have been a boon if I had lost another disk during the copy process, I am still going to be replacing these drives regardless. I plan to leave the drives in the array for the time being as I rebuild each parity drive one at a time instead of all at once, since they seem to still be functioning and parity of their own.
